# Correct way to connect to Google Cloud Storage from Android clients

Tags: android, google-app-engine, client, google-cloud-storage

I have been searching around and have found several examples of ways to connect to Cloud Storage from Android clients but these methods are quite old now. This is generally using a p12 file and newer examples show .json files to hold settings.

I have looked at this... https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-java-samples and it sais "Note: This client library is separate from the Google Cloud Storage client library, another option for interfacing with the the JSON API using Java." giving multiple options!

So my question is.. What is the correct way to implement the client (Android) side of Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Cloud Storage JSON API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/storage/v1) is an older, auto-generated client that is used as the underpinnings for the newer, under-development [Google Cloud Java Client for Storage](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-storage). The latter is part of the [`google-cloud` project](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.3.0/index.html), and aims to reduce the amount of boilerplate code needed to interact with the service. If you have a pointer to your Android sample that needs updating, we can take a look.

Another option for mobile development is to use [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/), which ultimately writes into Google Cloud Storage. Firebase is all about mobile and untrusted clients, and provides additional security rules that allow you to provide access to [users that do not have a Google account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users#sign-in_providers).

Comment: Okay so Google's interface is currently mixed between these two projects. I have Firebase setup with my app for auth so I will have a look into that option :) I'll mark this as correct as it lays out a good starting point to the google implementation.